# Split a string from user input in C when you don't know how long the string will be

Tags: c

Need to read an input string from a user. If the length of the string is an even number I need to split the string in halves. If the length of the string is odd, split the string into two strings where the first part has one more character than the second part. Output the two strings it created. For example:

Input: `OddAndEven` Output:

`OddAn`

`dEven`

Input: `OddOrEven` Output:

`OddOr`

`Even`

Comment: you can call strlen and add whatever logic you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code. It relies heavily on [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite). Other than that, it should be pretty self-explanatory. `fwrite` is defined as `size_t fwrite(const void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream);`. I used it primarily to control the size of the printed string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (strlen(argv[1]) % 2 == 0) {
        fwrite(argv[1], sizeof(char), strlen(argv[1]) / 2, stdout);
        printf("\n");
        fwrite((argv[1] + strlen(argv[1]) / 2), sizeof(char), strlen(argv[1]) / 2, stdout);
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        fwrite(argv[1], sizeof(char), (strlen(argv[1]) / 2) + 1, stdout);
        printf("\n");
        fwrite((argv[1] + (strlen(argv[1]) / 2) + 1), sizeof(char), (strlen(argv[1]) / 2) + 1, stdout);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```